# Keycloak reauthenticate an Authenticated user with a different client

Tags: keycloak, token-exchange

If I have a user that has authenticated with keycloak with public client C1 under realm R is there an endpoint I can hit in keycloak that will generate a new access token for a different public client C2 under the same realm R?

**[Update #1]**
I tried using the refresh token to obtain a new access token for C2 client but I get the following error:

`Invalid refresh token. Token client and authorized client don't match`

**[Update #2]**
So, the above gave me the idea of trying to use the exchange token grant type and I have it working now.

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://myhost.com.au/auth/realms/<my realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data-urlencode 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange' \
  --data-urlencode 'subject_token=<c1 access token>' \
  --data-urlencode 'subject_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token' \
  --data-urlencode 'requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token' \
  --data-urlencode 'client_id=<c2 client id>'
```

Comment: Why do you want to genrate new access token, if they are under same realm?

Comment: @ravthiru to get the scopes / claims of the new client into the access token.

Comment: @ravthiru his questions totally makes sense: see https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_role_scope_mappings realm roles aren't necessarilly exposed in an access token for all clients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question makes sense. Unfortunately the role scope mapping documentation is elusive about how to generate a new access token when switching to a different client.

There is an [Oauth2 RFC about token exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693). As of [Keycloak 11.0.2 token exchange is documented as a technology preview](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_token-exchange) and has to be enabled with `-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.token_exchange=enabled`

You can exchange tokens this way (actually taken from the question):

```
Method: POST
URL: https://<keycloak.host>/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token
Body type: x-www-form-urlencoded
Form fields:    
. grant_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange
. subject_token: <C1-access-token> 
. subject_token_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token
. requested_token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token
. client_id: <C2-client-id>
```

Here is some context from the ["role scope mapping" documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_role_scope_mappings) intended for other readers.

> When an OIDC access token or SAML assertion is created, all the user
> role mappings of the user are, by default, added as claims within the
> token or assertion. [...] access tokens are digitally signed and can
> actually be re-used by the application to invoke on other remotely
> secured REST services. This means that if an application gets
> compromised or there is a rogue client registered with the realm,
> attackers can get access tokens that have a broad range of permissions
> and your whole network is compromised. This is where role scope
> mappings becomes important.
>
> Role Scope Mappings is a way to limit the roles that get declared
> inside an access token. When a client requests that a user be
> authenticated, the access token they receive back will only contain
> the role mappings you’ve explicitly specified for the client’s scope.
>
> [...] To change this default behavior, you must explicitly turn off
> the Full Scope Allowed switch and declare the specific roles you want
> in each individual client. Alternatively, you can also use client
> scopes to define the same role scope mappings for a whole set of
> clients.

Comment: @ShaneRowatt alright, thanks for letting me know. I updated my answer with your solution and extra references for future readers.