# Authenticate keycloak client with another client

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-connect

I currently have two APIs with their confidential clients on keycloak.

So:

- API1 - client1
- API2 - client2

I don't know if I'm looking in the right way, but I want to protect an endpoint of my API2 for use it from my API1. Can I get a token relative to client1 and use it as another user token? Or do I need another authentication process?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried it or even searched for it? Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/63948830/2290153